# multiple linux terminals send commands to all windows at the same time

Tags: linux, terminal

Say for example that I have 3 terminals open (i.e. [gnome-terminal](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Gnome-terminal) or [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/)) and would like to group them together to send commands to all of them at the same time while typing on 1 single terminal.

I want the option to disperse those terminals if I need to issue 1 command in a particular terminal. Is there any terminal application that could provide this capability? I've tried  [keyboardcast](https://launchpad.net/keyboardcast) and is not exactly what i am looking for, since you have to type your command in a popup window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a program called terminator, It does exactly what you want :)

<s>http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html</s>

[EDIT] https://gnome-terminator.org/

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the right project? Or do you actually mean gnome terminator? https://gnome-terminator.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you want a non-GUI based approach you can also use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to send to multiple sessions as explained [here](http://masterofnull.com/2011/10/10/tmux-interact-with-any-or-all-panes/) - basically it works by using the following tmux command in a loop (if necessary):

```
tmux send-keys -t session_id your_command C-m
```

There's also an enhancement of tmux, called [wemux](https://github.com/zolrath/wemux),  that supports paired, mirrored, and rogue modes.

Answer (score 1):

If you use panes in tmux instead of separate terminals, you can use 'synchronize-panes' to send the same input to multiple panes. Plus you can bind the command to a key in `.tmux.conf` to easily turn it on and off.

```
# sends input to all panes in a given window.
bind e setw synchronize-panes on
bind E setw synchronize-panes off
```

see https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on: https://github.com/chabou/hyper-broadcast for Hyper terminal https://hyper.is/ . You can target individual tabs and/or other options of targeting which terminals.  I use this on windows although there is no reason you could not also use this on linux.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open several tabs/windows in konsole, you can direct the keyboard input from one of them into the others. Simply select menu Edit -> Copy Input To ... -> All Tabs/Select .../None.